# Problems with Octave impz function, in the moment I plot results

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm very new to the Matlab and Octave "World". I've been suffering for some hours to make a simple script run. Problem is, my teacher wrote it on Matlab, and I can't find a way to make it work on Octave. The script finds the impulse answer for the system and plots the curve. Here it is:

```
b = [1]; a = [1, -1, 0.9]; n = [0:100];
h = impz(b,a,n);
stem(n,h);
subplot(1,1,1);
title('Impulse Response'); xlabel('n'); ylabel('h(n)');
```

The error is:

> error: stem: inconsistent sizes for X and Y error: called from
>       **stem**>check_stem_arg at line 276 column 11
>       **stem** at line 37 column 40
>       stem at line 127 column 8
>       questao6_lab2 at line 4 column 1

I understand it is because of the axis difference. Though, I don't understand why octave gives only a single value for h. The function Impz should describe a curve all along thee values of n, but i doesn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from `impz` returning a scalar in this case

```
octave-gui:26> h = impz (1, [1, -1, 0.9], 0:100)
h =  1
```

while you are expecting a vector with 100 elements (which is what Matlab does).  In Matlab, the third argument (`N`) can be a scalar stating the number of samples of the impulse response, or a vector specifying the values where to compute the impulse response.  In Octave, you can only specify a number of samples.  So do this instead:

```
h = impz (1, [1, -1, 0.9], 101);
```

In addition, it seems that Octave returns a row vector instead of a column vector so do this:

```
h = impz (1, [1, -1, 0.9], 101)(:);
```

The reason why I am using `(:)` instead of `.'` (transpose) is so that it continues working in the next version of the signal package where [this will be fixed](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/signal/rev/6230503125dc).  Alternatively, run `which impz` to find where is the source for Octave's `impz` function, and fix it there for yourself now.

Comment: Thank you very much carandraug, it worked! As I said, I'm very new to this, so I'd rather not tangle with the impz.m file by now. I''ll wait for the update.

I there any problem in returning a row vector instead of the column?